# NetLogo BehaviorSpace Slows after several experiments

Tags: netlogo

I am using BehaviorSpace. At first it worked great, completing 80 runs in less than one hour. After doing about 10 different experiments in BehaviorSpace, it is now running at a considerably slower rate (almost to a halt), and now I am getting an error of "out of memory". 
I use `clear-all` as the first command in my setup procedure, but it seems like NetLogo is holding some memory over from previous runs. I have tried switching to table output, and disabled spreadsheet output, but still got an out of memory error. 
I see several posts on BehaviorSpace memory issues, but I cannot seem to figure out why the models ran so quickly to start, and now hardly runs.
I am using NetLogo 5.0.5 on a server with 16 cores and 64 GB of RAM, and have models running in parallel.
Does anyone have an idea where this memory is being tied up, and how I can clear it?

Comment: Have you already increased the heap size using the instructions at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#howbig ?

Comment: I have increased the heap size, but what seemed to help most was simply shutting down NetLogo and starting again with a new session. This brought my speed back, and again over successive runs it begins to slow. Im not sure where this memory is being stored, but for now it seems that frequently starting NetLogo over solves my speed problem.

Comment: So, NetLogo is keeping in the memory each run, even when using the table output?