# Ever-increasing memory usage in netlogo headless behaviorspace

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

I'm trying to run a Netlogo model in behaviorspace, in headless mode, on a linux server.
My netlogo version is 5.3.1 (the 64b version).
The server has 32 cores with 64gigs of RAM.
I'm setting Xmx to 3072m.

After a few runs (~300) the memory usage is so high that I get a Java heap space error.

Surprisingly, the memory usage grows regularly, as if there were no flush-like function called between runs. And it gets to a point it shouldn't reach if I understand things well (for example, for 15 parallel threads it reaches 64000MB and beyond when it should stay around 15 * 3072 = 46080.

I'm using `ca` at setup so I thought everything was supposed to be flushed out between runs. I'm not opening any file from the code (I use the standard behaviorspace output, in table format, not spreadsheet), and I'm not using any extension.
I'm kind oh puzzled here. Is there something I should look at into behaviorspace specific parameterization that says to keeps track of variables, turtles, etc. between runs ? I couldn't find such a thing.

Could someone help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Thomas

Comment: For output, are you using table mode, spreadsheet mode, both, or neither? Spreadsheet mode is documented as storing all results in memory; see the user manual.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Seth. I'm using table only with the `--table` option when launching in command line on linux. I'm not calling `--spreadsheet`.

Comment: I'm at a loss for what else to suggest. What you're describing certainly isn't normal or common. You might try minimizing your model to see what elements must be present in the model for the issue to occur. You've verified that you *don't* see similar behavior with a simple built-in model (like Fire or Wolf-Sheep Predation or something)?

Comment: You might also try using a Java heap analyzer — perhaps it will show something obvious.

Comment: Ok I'll try both suggestions and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: This is weird. I'm getting the same increase in memory usage with the Wolf-Sheep Predation model. I actually beefed it up a little bit to be sure to see something (the map is 250*250 in my test version). I run it with this config :

sheep-reproduce 4 10 20

wolf-gain-from-food 20 30 50

initial-number-sheep 1000 2000
initial-number-wolves 100
grass? true
grass-regrowth-time 10 30 60
sheep-gain-from-food 4 10 20
wolf-reproduce 5 10 15
4 repetitions, measure at every steps (`count turtles` + `sum [energy] of turtles`), and I added `print behaviorspace-run-number` in the setup commands.

Comment: with Wolf-Sheep Predation, does the memory usage actually increase monotonically, and does it actually run out of memory eventually? it's normal for heap usage to gradually increase, but it should drop again after the garbage collector runs.

Comment: @ Thomas Delattre I believe I reported a similar issue: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728281/netlogo-behaviorspace-slows-after-several-experiments?noredirect=1#comment54927325_30728281) and only found shutting down NetLogo to be the solution to my problem. I'm curious if Thomas has found a better solution?